# OSGI : CXF exception with Karaf JAX-RS: No resource methods have been found for resource

Tags: rest, jax-rs, osgi, cxf, apache-karaf

I am getting an exception while creating a simple CXF web service with OSGI and Karaf.

Would really appreciate any comments/suggestions for fix.

Here is the description of my project and steps I followed:

1. Downloaded the Apache Karaf-4.0.7
2. Run the “mvn clean install” in the command line with the path to my project
3. Started Karaf console, and run the following commands

   ```
          feature:repo-add cxf 3.1.8
          feature:install cxf/3.1.8
   ```

Interface:

```
  public interface MyRestService { 
         String pingMe(String echo);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyRestServiceImpl implements MyRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{echo}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String pingMe(@PathParam("echo") String echo) {
        return "Knock Knock: " + echo + " !!";
    }
}
```

OSGI blueprint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.1.0 https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/tags/blueprint-0.3.1/blueprint-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/aries/blueprint/ext/blueprint-ext.xsd  
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
      http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd
    ">
    <cxf:bus id=”myBusId”>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging></cxf:logging>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <jaxrs:server id="myRestService" address="/RestProject/SimpleRestCall">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="myRestImpl" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="myRestImpl" class="com.rest.api.impl.MyRestServiceImpl" />  
</blueprint>
```

Features.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
    name="restAPI">

    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.8/xml/features</repository> 

    <feature name="test" description="simple test" version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT">
        <details>A Rest server</details>

        <!-- CXF and depdendencies -->
        <feature version="3.1.8">cxf-jaxrs</feature>

        <!-- Jackson and dependencies -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr339-api-2.0/2.6.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils/1.8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.7.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.7.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.7.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.7.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.github.fge/msg-simple/1.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.github.fge/btf/1.2</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1</bundle>

        <!-- The myRest Server -->
        <bundle>mvn:com.rest.ebb.test/myRest/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>

    </feature>

</features>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.rest.ebb.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>myRest-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.rest.ebb.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myRest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>MyRestServer</name>
    <description>A server for test</description>
    <url>.example.com</url>
   <properties>
   <cxf.version>3.1.8</cxf.version>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.ebb.rest.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Embed-Dependency>!org.osgi.core,*</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Import-Package>
                            !com.google.protobuf,!com.google.protobuf.*,
                            !com.jcraft.*,
                            !com.ning.*,
                            !groovy.lang,
                            !javassist,
                            !lzma.*,
                            !net.jpountz.*,
                            !org.apache.*,
                            !org.bouncycastle.*,
                            !org.codehaus.*,
                            !org.eclipse.*,
                            !org.jboss.*,
                            !rx,
                            !sun.security.*,
                            !net.bytebuddy.*,
                            !org.HdrHistogram,
                            !org.slf4j.event,
                            !org.xerial.*,
                            !sun.reflect,
                            !sun.misc,
                            !sun.util.calendar,
                            !com.sun.jdi.*,
                            !jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.*,
                            !javax.servlet,
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Errors:

Am not able to deploy osgi bundles in Karaf, and getting the following errors:

```
2017-01-06 11:00:39,340 | WARN  | pool-9-thread-1  | ResourceUtils                    | 141 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 3.1.8 | No resource methods have been found for reso
 class com.rest.api.impl.MyRestServiceImpl
2017-01-06 11:00:39,373 | ERROR | pool-9-thread-1  | AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean         | 141 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 3.1.8 | No resource classes found
2017-01-06 11:00:39,375 | WARN  | pool-9-thread-1  | BeanRecipe                       | 33 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.6.2 | Object to be destroyed is not an instance of Unwra
edBeanHolder, type: null
2017-01-06 11:00:39,385 | ERROR | pool-9-thread-1  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 33 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.6.2 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle mvn:com.abb.ecc.my/myRest/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean myRestService
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:738)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:848)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_51]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:255)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:186)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:724)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:411)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:276)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:300)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:269)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:265)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:255)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[43:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[43:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[43:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[43:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[43:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:731)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:486)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4541)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2172)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1286)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:846)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1176)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1074)[10:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.init(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:142)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_51]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:736)[33:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:317)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:159)
        ... 42 more
```

Comment: Can you try not to use the interface, just make your REST implementation and annotation on the class `MyRestServiceImpl`; We had some issues with interfcaes in the past and now all our REST service are defined in Classes only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the jax-rs annotations on the service interface.

Another possible cause is that the annotation package is not imported. You block a lot of imports in your pom. Can you check without these definitions.

Comment: I tried this way too but didn't help much. Got the same error.    

 Thanks @Christian Schneider.

Comment: @Sarav Which annotation did you put in the interface? It seems JAX-RS is quite sensitive on which one you declare there.

Comment: @ruffp Am using the following JAX-RS annotations in the interface:

Comment: @Path("/")


public interface MyRestService { 


  @GET


  @Path("/{echo}")


     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)


 public String pingMe(@PathParam("echo") String echo);

Comment: Try to remove just the @Path on the interface but let only annotations on the method (still in the interface).

Comment: @ruffp I tried that way too, but still the same issue is prevails.

Comment: @Sarav Did you try my other suggestion to remove totally the interface and have only a class? Just to test and check even in the future you'll need the Interface.

Comment: @ruff I did tried that way too (without the interface) but still no luck as I got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

On my side your code works but I had to change the following things:

1. Remove the cxf:bus from the blueprint
2. Remove the `@Path` on the implementation class
3. Change the import section in the `pom.xml`

Implementation:

```
package com.mycompany.testcxf;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class MyRestServiceImpl implements MyRestService {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("/{echo}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String pingMe(@PathParam("echo") String echo) {
        return "Knock Knock: " + echo + " !!";
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<osgi.export.package>{local-packages}</osgi.export.package>
<osgi.import.package>
    com.mycompany.testcxf*,
    *
</osgi.import.package>
```

and I only import the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note I cannot test the CXF version 3 as you because my OSGI container is bound to this version. However this setup works perfectly for me, then it could be an issue with the CXF version and some incompatibilities with the embedded http server (Jetty?).

My setup is `ServiceMix 5.1.4` with:

- Version 2.3.9 of Apache Karaf
- Version 2.13.3 of Camel
- Version 2.7.13 of CXF

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but it throws another error saying:

org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Element ref must have a valid component-id attribute


Thank you @ruffp.

Comment: @sarav I updated my answer and it works with my setup. Can you give a try with cxf v3 an let me know?